# Let E1, E2 Equivalence relations on A, Prove or disprove :

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Let E1, E2 Equivalence relations on A, Prove or disprove :

1) E1 ∩ E2 an equivalence relation on A

2) E1 ∪ E2 an equivalence relation on A

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Statement 1 is true. You should prove that the new relation is reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

Statement 2 is false. You should try to make a counterexample in which transitivity fails. Try $A=\{1,2,3\}$.